# Launch Word of OpenOffice from web app Java and JS?

Tags: java

I have a web application created in Java EE with Javascript and I need to launch the Word or Open Office application from the application to edit a document temporarily and when saving or closing it, it is saved in the system as BLOB.

How can I do it?
Exist any method?

Many thanks

Comment: Launch it where? On the client? On the server?

Comment: If you want to execute it on the client, forget it. That's not possible due to security reasons. It would be possible on the server (to run word), but I guess you'd be better off with a file upload of the updated file, since I guess it's utterly messy to forward any input to it.

Comment: I want to run OpenOffice from the client side, because the system is on a server and it runs on different computers, which must be edited with OpenOffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about doing this client-side:

- To lauch OpenOffice Writer ("Word" is MS Office, not OpenOffice): If you open a link to an `.odt` resource (MIME type: `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`), the browser will offer to download it (most likely) or open it within the browser (less likely but some may) to allow the user to edit it locally with whatever softwaer they have installed to do that (OpenOffice, LibreOffice, or even MS Office [Office 365 supports that format]).
- To get the edited version back: You'll need the user to identify the temporary file (via an `input type="file"` element or drag-and-drop). Then either post that to the server as part of a form, or read it locally via a `FileReader`'s `readAsArrayBuffer` method and send the resulting Blob to the server.

This isn't as seamless as what you describe, but it's pretty much what's available in a cross-browser, standards-compliant way if you want the user editing in OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly, it's the same way I see, download the file, edit it locally and upload the edited file, the problem is to launch the editor from the web and also detect the temporary file and upload it automatically without the need to use drag and drop